# Theming Engine only applies to some images/icons?

Tags: 2013, css, branding, theme

I'm using a custom spcolor file with my masterpage that is based on Seattle.

I've applied some icons to be recolored by the theming engine and this works fine for most of the icons but i'm unable to recolor images that are not a part of the spcommon.png file.

This is my cssregistration in my masterpage.

```
<SharePoint:CssRegistration Name="<%$SPUrl:~SiteCollection/Style Library/~language/Themable/myProject.css%>" runat="server" after="Themable/corev15.css" />
```

However it does not work at all.

```
/*[RecolorImage(themeColor:"SearchURL", method:"Filling", includeRectangle:{x:251,y:82,width:20,height:18})]*/
background-image: url("/_layouts/15/images/spcommon.png?rev=23");

/*[RecolorImage(themeColor:"EmphasisHoverBorder", method:"Filling", includeRectangle:{x:1,y:30,width:97,height:97})]*/
background-image: url("/_layouts/15/images/spcommon.png?rev=23");

/*[RecolorImage(themeColor:"PageBackground", method:"Filling", includeRectangle:{x:104,y:178,width:21,height:16})]*/
background-image: url("/_layouts/15/images/spcommon.png?rev=23");

/*[RecolorImage(themeColor:"StrongLines", method:"Filling", includeRectangle:{x:179,y:95,width:18,height:17})]*/
background-image: url("/_layouts/15/images/spcommon.png?rev=23");

/*[RecolorImage(themeColor:"SearchURL", method:"Filling", includeRectangle:{x:215,y:174,width:16,height:16})]*/
background-image: url("/_layouts/15/images/spcommon.png?rev=23");
```

All icons above works (recoloring the spcommon) but i can't recolor this one:

```
/*[RecolorImage(themeColor:"EmphasisHoverBorder",method:"Tinting")]*/
background-image: url("/_layouts/15/images/SharePointFoundation16.png?rev=23");
```

Are the limitations of the theming engine to only apply recoloring of icons to the spcommon image?

Comment: I think you can recolor pretty much any image, even your own custom made images. perhaps it is having trouble finding/matching the image or that image has some specificity that is somehow unable to be parsed

Comment: similar thread: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/silverlight/en-US/6c45f374-4d78-40fe-88af-1eddc27dac98/recolor-image-not-working-for-multiple-images?forum=sharepointcustomization